# Use custom CSS for radio buttons in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I want some customized radio buttons in Jquery mobile page. So I used CSS to customize the radio buttons. But unfortunately, the used CSS is overided by the jquery default css.

My HTML code snippet is as follows.

```
<div class="answers">
        <label class="container-quiz">Doe
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="doe" name="answer2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container-quiz">Kit
            <input type="radio" value="kit" name="answer2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container-quiz">Buck
            <input type="radio" value="buck" name="answer2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container-quiz">Hare
            <input type="radio" value="hare" name="answer2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows

```
.container-quiz {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container-quiz input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container-quiz:hover input ~ .checkmark {
background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container-quiz input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container-quiz input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container-quiz .checkmark:after {
  top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f4364c;
}
```

When I remove the jquery js scripts from the `<head>` I get the result which I want and it is like below.

[image]

But when I have jquery I don't get the result I want.

[image]

Comment: JQuery is a  is a JavaScript Library it should not override your css styling, are you referring to bootstrap?

Comment: why are jquery scripts in your <head> in the first place? thats not where they belong. as suii sugest do you by any chance mean Bootstrap? Jquery can affect your css styling if you have any scripts running that alter your CSS. So to really answer we need:
- your full html including <head> tag 
- your scripts that are getting executed as Jquery

Comment: I am using JQuery mobile CSS styles. I use ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />` in my `<head>` tag to import it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style is completely diffrent from that of JQM and You already have a complete CSS for Your radio buttons.
So the fastest way is to tell JQM to avoid to enhance that elements. Add `data-role="none"` to Your inputs.

```
<div class="answers">
    <label class="container-quiz">Doe
        <input data-role="none" type="radio" checked="checked" value="doe" name="answer2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container-quiz">Kit
        <input data-role="none" type="radio" value="kit" name="answer2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container-quiz">Buck
        <input data-role="none" type="radio" value="buck" name="answer2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container-quiz">Hare
        <input data-role="none" type="radio" value="hare" name="answer2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Otherwise, You need to override the JQM `.ui-radio-off, .ui-radio-on, .ui-radio-off:after, .ui-radio-on:after` styles (the standard radio buttons are already hidden by JQM).

Answer (score -2):

Use !important property on properties which are being overriden

Comment: I tried this. But it didn't work

Comment: @JanethFernando Can you please create a fiddle so I can see what's going on